# How to convert this data set to arff format for weka

Tags: java, csv, weka, arff

I have a groceries dataset which contains over 9000 transaction records of 170+ items.
I need to load it to weka. 
I tried to convert it to arff with weka conversion tools, but I got the following error:

```
java.io.IO Exception 
Wrong number of values ,Read 32 ,expected 4, 
read Token[EOL] line 2 problem encountered in line 2
```

I figured out that I need to preprocess the data manually to load it.

```
citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups
tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee
whole milk
pip fruit,yogurt,cream cheese ,meat spreads
rolls/buns
pot plants
whole milk,cereals
```

The file doesn't contain any header or topics. How can I convert it to the arff format?

Comment: i tried the weka converter thats when i got the IOException error

Comment: please mind adding this comment onto your question.

Comment: Fixed grammar and spelling. Formatted the code properly.

Comment: start here http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html . You can manually create an arff file.